# Remove Side drawer of an Activity programmatically

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have an Activity which has a layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_filter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_filter" />


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/lst_tourist_places"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none"/>
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/filter_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/container_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_filter"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/filter"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_categories"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/categories"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_categories" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/filter_radio_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_historical_places"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:button="@drawable/radio_btn"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_categories" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_parks_gardens"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:button="@drawable/radio_btn"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_categories" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_religious_places"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:button="@drawable/radio_btn"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_categories" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_show_all"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:button="@drawable/radio_btn"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_categories" />

            </RadioGroup>


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my `Activity` I want to Programmatically remove the `filter_ll` i.e., the side drawer and make it a normal activity based on the `Intent Extra`.

Comment: What do you mean by removing side drawer? removing or hiding?

Comment: I don't want user to access the drawer, just remove it

Comment: That is the question I asked how to hide it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, hide the button which is used to access it. Also, add this,

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

where `mDrawerLayout` is your `ActionBarDrawerToggle` object in your activity. If you are doing this in a fragment, just add the above code with activity's reference like,

```
mActivity.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```